# WhatsApp bot in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple WhatsApp bot using python. But the bot doesn't send the message after it writes the automated message.

This is the code I have written

```py
import pywhatkit

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+20100081978767","Whatsapp bot",5,24)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the message is not sent, is because of the time you set. Have a look at the parameters -

```
Syntax: pywhatkit.sendmsg(“receiver mobile number”,”message”,hours,minutes)

Parameters:

Receiver mobile number: The Receiver’s mobile number must be in string format and the country code must be mentioned before the mobile number.

Message: Message to be sent(Must be in string format).

Hours: This module follows the 24 hrs time format.

Minutes: Mention minutes of the scheduled time for the message(00-59).
```

Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-pywhatkit-module/)

So, in your code, `pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+20100081978767", "Whatsapp bot",5,24)`, 5 and 24 actually means that the message will be sent at `5:24 am` tomorrow.

So, try changing time so that you can send the message today.

Comment: I tried it with different time with the way you told me about it, but it didn't work

Comment: I suggest you take a tutorial on pywhatkit then, you can understand how to use it. You can use the link in the answer for a simple one.